# Toolbox with fixed position

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create a toolbox with fixed position using following code snippet.

```css
#controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 10%;
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.separator {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 90%;
  position: inherit;
  bottom: 5%;
}
#chalk-color,
#thickness,
#board-color,
#eraser,
#about {
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <input type="color" id="chalk-color" />
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input type="color" id="board-color">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input type="button" id="eraser" value="Erase">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input id="thickness">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <span id="about">About</span>
</div>
```

As you see in the code snippet, I'm trying to make height of all tools to `100%`. However, tools appears in different sizes and with different alignments. Why this problem is happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline element (such as `span`) do not have width, height, padding or margins. Set them to `display: inline-block` to allow for those.

Use `vertical-align: middle` to align at center instead of baseline.

Use `box-sizing: border-box` to make sure it's `100%` in height including the padding.

```css
#controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 10%;
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.separator {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 90%;
  position: inherit;
  bottom: 5%;
}
#chalk-color,
#thickness,
#board-color,
#eraser,
#about {
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <input type="color" id="chalk-color" />
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input type="color" id="board-color">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input type="button" id="eraser" value="Erase">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input id="thickness">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <span id="about">About</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now your toolbars are `inline` - make them `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align` them and there you go!

```
#chalk-color,
#thickness,
#board-color,
#eraser,
#about {
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
#controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 10%;
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.separator {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 90%;
  position: inherit;
  bottom: 5%;
}
#chalk-color,
#thickness,
#board-color,
#eraser,
#about {
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <input type="color" id="chalk-color" />
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input type="color" id="board-color">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input type="button" id="eraser" value="Erase">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <input id="thickness">
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <span id="about">About</span>
</div>
```